# Converting PowerQuery instruction into Python script

Tags: python, powerquery

I have been using a PowerQuery function to asses if I have unique hierarchies in a column in PowerBI.
Unfortunately, my dataset has increased considerably and I thought a Python script might help in speeding up the data load.

Column ID and string are the ones from the source data and column result should check for each row of a column to see if the value already exists as part of a larger string or is identical to a string in the column
Column string acts like a hierarchy. So for example, where we have "ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL" we have a hierarchy on Level 1, Level 2, Level 3 and Level 4. Where we have "GHI,JKL" I would like to mark it as "already exists" because this cell represents Level 3 and Level 4 out of a hierarchy that has already been found.

| ID | string | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL" | unique |
| 2 | "DEF,GHI,JKL" | already exists |
| 3 | "MNO,PQR" | unique |
| 4 | "STU" | unique |
| 5 | "GHI,JKL" | already exists |
| 6 | "JKL" | already exists |
| 7 | "STU" | already exists |

Below is the PowerQuery code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlRQ0lFydHLWcXF103H38NTx8vZRUIrViVYyAslgiBqDRH39/HUCAoMgIiYgkeCQUAjPFMRD0WEGEoHzzBGqYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ID = _t, string = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "result", each 
let a = List.Range(#"Changed Type"[string], 0,[ID]-1 ),
b = List.FindText(a, [string]),
c = if List.Count(b) > 0 then "already exists" else "unique"
in c
)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

'

What Python functions should be used in order to replicate the above PowerQuery code?